# Change UINavigationController color and font

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm writing my app router like this:

```
final class AppRouter {

    let navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(window: UIWindow) {
        navigationController = UINavigationController()
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
...
}
```

I'm calling router initialiser in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

I was trying to change it style (colour, font and other) by changing it properties, child properties, using `UINavigationBar.appearance()`

Nothing works. I was setting `translucent` to false. Only storyboard changes are making any effect, but then I have storyboard based navigation, that I don't want to have.
I have seen many posts about this issue, nothing is working.

If someone have cookbook, that is working on newest iOS (currently 11.4), please share!

Edit:

Like I said making changes like:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = color
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

this is used in didFinishLaunching.

or in constructor:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color
```

Both methods fail to set color of navigation controller bar.

Edit 2:
App delegate calls:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    appRouter = AppRouter(window: window)
    return true
}
```

Comment: show the code that is not working + how you integrate and use `AppRouter`

Comment: Can you add your `AppDelegate` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below extension for `UINavigationController`

```
     extension UINavigationController
     {
        func setMainTopNavigationBarAttribute() -> Void
        {

             self.navigationBar.shadowImage     = UIImage()
             self.navigationBar.isTranslucent   = false
             self.navigationBar.barTintColor    = UIColor.black
             self.navigationBar.tintColor       = UIColor.white
             self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let navBarAttributesDictionary: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]? = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18.0)
        ]
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
         }
      }

    final class AppRouter {

        let navigationController: UINavigationController

        init(window: UIWindow) {
            navigationController = UINavigationController()
            window.rootViewController = navigationController
            navigationController.setMainTopNavigationBarAttribute() 
    }
```

Comment: I’ll check that.

Comment: It is working, I added some improvements:
`struct NavBarStyle{
    var shadowImage: UIImage?
    var isTranslucent = true
    var barTintColor = UIColor.orange
    var tintColor = UIColor.brown
    var backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    var navBarAttributesDictionary: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]? = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18.0)!
    ]
}

extension UINavigationController
{
    func setMainTopNavigationBarAttribute(style: NavBarStyle) -> Void
    {  ...}`